# importing a javascript module

Tags: javascript, html, import, module

I'm trying to develop javascript that uses the three.js package, and I'm stuck at an early step of trying to import a module. In the html, I have

`<script src="main.mj"></script>`

And then in main.js I have

`import * as THREE from './js/three.module.js';`

But, my browser won't load the page, giving the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module". If I change the html code to read

`<script src="main.mj" type=module></script>`

Then I get

"Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

import * as THREE from './js/three.module.js';

I am pretty new to javascript, and I'd appreciate any advice.  I'm editing on a local maching running an nginx webserver on localhost.

Comment: It should be `mjs` and not `mj`. Also, make sure that your server is configured to serve `mjs` files with MIME type `text/javascript`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, it was main.mjs. Any idea on how to setup nginx for text/javascript? The documentation I've found looks like it defaults to text.

Comment: https://semisignal.com/serving-mjs-files-with-nginx/

Comment: Alternatively, use regular `.js` as extension. As long as you have `type="module"` it's still loaded as ES module.

Comment: When I use <script src="main.mj" type=module></script>' I get the second error about strict "MIME type checking".

Comment: Sorry, same typo, I meant <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>

Comment: Okay, I'm pretty sure that this is an nginx configuration issue. I'm going to start a new thread.